# How can I access Google developers documents on my Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to access google documentation while coding , for example if I were creating a "textview", I want to refer to the android documentation about it. For this I generally open a browser search it and find its implementation or usage, Is there a keyboard shortcut that lets me do all this within the IDE itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
Quick documentation lookup  Control+Q for windows and Control+J for Mac